# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: initialData is null - my components are wrapped in a single div but still getting the error

Tags: laravel, modal-dialog, components, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I am getting an initial data is null error.  This has been talked about github forum, however, the answer was that the component was not wrapped in a single div.  My components are.  So I am still getting:

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: initialData is null

I have a simple button that runs a function when clicked

[image]

which is produced by this code:

```
<div class="mx-0 col-span-1 block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700 mb-0">
    <x-green-button-sm class="px-0 mx-0" title="Add a New person to the family." wire:click="createChild">
       <h3 class="my-0 text-xss">Add Child</h3>
    </x-green-button-sm>

   @livewire('admin.shared.edit-add-child', ['showEditAddChildModal' => $showEditAddChildModal,
             'editadd' => 'add',  'userid' => $user->id,  'registrantOrAdmin' => $registrantOrAdmin])
 </div>
```

Which calls this function in the component

```
public function createChild(){
        $this->showEditAddChildModal = true;
 }
```

And notice that the livewire component above is passed the value of $showEditAddChildModal

The beginning of the admin.shared.edit-add-child blade component is:

```
<div>

<form wire:submit.prevent="save">
    <x-modal.dialog wire:model="showEditAddChildModal">
......
.....
</div>  // the blade component is contained in a single div as required
```

so the effort is to make the model visible obviously.  The admin.shared.edit-add-child blade  blade makes reference to models (public properties) like this

```
wire:model.debounce.500ms="editChild.firstname"
```

the EditAddChild.php component is set up like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Admin\Shared;

use App\Models\Person;
use Livewire\Component;

class EditAddChild extends Component
{
    public $showEditAddChildModal = false;

//(if i set the above true, the modal does show up.)

    public $userid;
    public $txtmsgp;

    public $fullname;
    public $registrantOrAdmin;
    public $editadd;

    public $editChild; 
// (I started  with public Person $editChild but the system balked at //initializing a typed variable in the mount() function)

    public $dateOfBirth;
```

Below, note that the $this->editadd variable is passed in the @livewire call seen above.  The mount() function in the EditAddChild.php component is:

```
public function mount(){
    if($this->editadd == 'add')
        $this->editChild = $this->addNewChild();
}
```

addNewChild() is:

```
public function addNewChild()
    {

        return Person::make(['added_by' => auth()->user()->id,
            'updated_by' => null,
            'family_type' => 'child',
            'firstname' => '',
            'lastname' => '',
            'pronouns' => 'u',
            'sex' => 'u',
            'dob' => now(),
            'age_today' => 0,
            'mobile_phone' => null,
            'receive_texts' => 'u',
            'email' => '',
            'allow_emails' => 'u',
            'member' => 'u',
            'allow_photos' => 'u',
            'show' => 0,
        ]);
}
```

when i click on the add child button to change the x-show variable to true, the modal does not show and the console reports this:

[image]

My apologies, but I thought I would list the entire modal coponent as well.  There are two parts [dialog.blade.php] :

```
@props(['id' => null, 'maxWidth' => null])

<x-modal :id="$id" :maxWidth="$maxWidth" {{ $attributes }}>
    <div class="px-6 py-4">
        <div class="text-lg">
            {{ $title }}
        </div>

        <div class="mt-4">
            {{ $content }}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="px-6 py-4 bg-gray-100 text-right">
        {{ $footer }}
    </div>
</x-modal>
```

the second part being [modal.bade.php]:

```
@props(['id', 'maxWidth'])

@php
$id = $id ?? md5($attributes->wire('model'));

$maxWidth = [
    'sm' => 'sm:max-w-sm',
    'md' => 'sm:max-w-md',
    'lg' => 'sm:max-w-lg',
    'xl' => 'sm:max-w-xl',
    '2xl' => 'sm:max-w-2xl',
    '3xl' => 'sm:max-w-3xl',
    '4xl' => 'sm:max-w-4xl',
    '5xl' => 'sm:max-w-5xl',
    '6xl' => 'sm:max-w-6xl',
    '7xl' => 'sm:max-w-7xl',

][$maxWidth ?? '3xl'];
@endphp

<div
    x-data="{
        show: @entangle($attributes->wire('model')).defer,
        focusables() {
            // All focusable element types...
            let selector = 'a, button, input, textarea, select, details, [tabindex]:not([tabindex=\'-1\'])'

            return [...$el.querySelectorAll(selector)]
                // All non-disabled elements...
                .filter(el => ! el.hasAttribute('disabled'))
        },
        firstFocusable() { return this.focusables()[0] },
        lastFocusable() { return this.focusables().slice(-1)[0] },
        nextFocusable() { return this.focusables()[this.nextFocusableIndex()] || this.firstFocusable() },
        prevFocusable() { return this.focusables()[this.prevFocusableIndex()] || this.lastFocusable() },
        nextFocusableIndex() { return (this.focusables().indexOf(document.activeElement) + 1) % (this.focusables().length + 1) },
        prevFocusableIndex() { return Math.max(0, this.focusables().indexOf(document.activeElement)) -1 },
    }"
    x-init="$watch('show', value => {
        if (value) {
            document.body.classList.add('overflow-y-hidden');
        } else {
            document.body.classList.remove('overflow-y-hidden');
        }
    })"
    x-on:close.stop="show = false"
    x-on:keydown.escape.window="show = false"
    x-on:keydown.tab.prevent="$event.shiftKey || nextFocusable().focus()"
    x-on:keydown.shift.tab.prevent="prevFocusable().focus()"
    x-show="show"
    id="{{ $id }}"
    class="overflow-auto jetstream-modal fixed inset-0 overflow-y-auto px-4 py-6 sm:px-0 z-50"
    style="display: none;"
>
    <div x-show="show" class="fixed inset-0 transform transition-all" x-on:click="show = false"
                    x-transition:enter="ease-out duration-3000"
                    x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0"
                    x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100"
                    x-transition:leave="ease-in duration-3000"
                    x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100"
                    x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0">
        <div class="absolute inset-0 bg-gray-500 opacity-75"></div>
    </div>

    <div x-show="show" class="mb-6 bg-white rounded-lg overflow-hidden shadow-xl transform transition-all sm:w-full {{ $maxWidth }} sm:mx-auto"
                    x-transition:enter="ease-out duration-300"
                    x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"
                    x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
                    x-transition:leave="ease-in duration-200"
                    x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
                    x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95">
        {{ $slot }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding `:wire:key="uniqid()"` or `key(uniqid())` worked for me

```
<livewire:components.confirmation :wire:key="uniqid()"/>
```

or

```
@livewire("components.tags", ["tags"=> $tags], key(uniqid()))
```

If the above solution still not resolve your issue then goto the component and check if you have added `wire:key` in the root element which basically duplicated the key passed from `@livewire` `<livewire` then remove it from and then check the issue again.

Answer (score 1):

Please check in here

```
@livewire('admin.shared.edit-add-child', ['showEditChildModal' => $showEditAddChildModal,
             'editadd' => 'add',  'userid' => $user->id,  'registrantOrAdmin' => $registrantOrAdmin])
```

precisely at "'showEditChildModal' => $showEditAddChildModal" part. You're binding the parent property ($showEditAddChildModal) to the child ('showEditChildModal'), but in the child component that property doesn't exist, instead you have declared the property as next:

```
public $showEditAddChildModal = false;
```

It's a typo of you should fix it???

Comment: thank you.  I fixed the typo, and I get the same result.  Ugh.
`
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Admin\Shared;

use App\Models\Person;
use Livewire\Component;

class EditAddChild extends Component
{
    public $showEditAddChildModal = true;
    public $userid;
    public $txtmsgp;
`
`
@livewire('admin.shared.edit-add-child', ['showEditAddChildModal' => true,
      'editadd' => 'add',
      'userid' => $user->id,
      'registrantOrAdmin' => $registrantOrAdmin])
`